# Weekly new random sorting for WordPress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

Currently I'm looking for an idea to create a weekly new random sorting for wordpress posts of a custom type. I need it for a page with paid ads. Nobody should have a permanent position advantage. It would be great if the new random sorting were done automatically every week. It can also be triggered manually using a button in the backend.

Is there a plugin for this? I also have my own programming skills, but currently I am missing an approach for this project. Does somebody has any idea? Can the sorting in the custom loop depend on the calendar week?

Beste regards, Marvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a meta field "priority" and order by that. Once a week, you just set that field with a script, making any random order.

Since it only changes weekly, that's probably a lot easier than building a complex sorting logic that relies on the week number.

Comment: thank you for your idea! a meta field "priority" is the first senseful step :) I have never written a script, which runs at a fixed interval. will i need to use cronjobs?

Comment: Yes, a cron job would be the right tool. You can either set up a cron job that runs your script via an HTTP request or you can use WordPress' wp-cron feature and make it "the wordpress way". A normal cron job might be easier because you don't have to get into WP for it.